# Dynamically changing a NSWindow's contentViewController

Tags: macos, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I have an `NSWindowController` and an `NSViewController`, both configured in a storyboard.

- When I set the `contentViewController` in Interface Builder, everything works as expected.
- When I set the `contentViewController` programmatically in `windowDidLoad` everything works as expected.

Now I'm trying to update the content view controller in response to a toolbar button click (below).

```
@IBAction func toolbarButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    contentViewController = storyboard?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "VC") as! NSViewController?
}
```

This assignment causes `viewWillAppear` to be called on the view controller, but at that point the content view doesn't have a window assigned.

Why is this? Is it possible to dynamically change a window's `contentViewController` like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like:

- When the content view is configured in storyboard or `windowDidLoad`, the view already has a window by the time `viewWillAppear` gets called, i.e. when the window itself appears.
- When the content view is set after the window has appeared, `viewWillAppear` gets called to indicate that the content view will be added to the window; the view has no window until `viewWillLayout` is called.

I was using the window to access the current document, so my solution was to access the document before updating the content and use that to configure the content view controller.